# Android : How to dynamically change Locale for application level resources?

Tags: android, localization, android-application-class

To change the locale, I am using method of creating a new Context and passing it into `#super.attachBaseContext`.

This works fine for the Activities, since in my use-case it is applicable in the initial activities before the main workflow starts, so I can get away with simply calling `#Activity.recreate()` and the `attachBaseContext` will be called again.

However, this is not the case with Application class and **I am using Application Context to load resources where a Context is not easily available, such as View Models, Repositories, and Helper classes.**

So the locales are not updated when accessed using Application Context, since I am not letting the application class know, anywhere, that the resources have changed. `#Application.attachBaseContext` can only be called once, and I could not find a way to recreate the application class, and it will be a bad user experience as well.

So is there a way to reload Application-level resources dynamically? Is there a way to recreate the application class?

How can we change Locale on Application level resources dynamically?

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    newBase?.let {
        val langCode : String = LocaleHelper().getCurrentLocale().code
        toast("attachBaseContext")
        val context : Context = changeLang(it, langCode)
        super.attachBaseContext(context)
    } ?: run {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
    }
}

private fun changeLang(newContext: Context, langCode: String): ContextWrapper {
    var context = newContext
    val sysLocale: Locale

    val rs = context.resources
    val config = rs.configuration

    if (langCode != "") {
        val locale = Locale(langCode)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            config.setLocale(locale)
        } else {
            config.locale = locale
        }
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config)
    }

    return ContextWrapper(context)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot for the same topic ending with using [Android-Localization](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-Localization) as Android localization is based on device language by default

NB: you might face issues on android 6.0 and below using Android-Localization library so test it well!

Comment: I am guessing it would handle the issue mentioned here. If so, are there any issues that you faced with this library?

Comment: With an old version yes, I faced a UI problem with dialog positive button, also in android 6.0 and below the whole library was not working. if your usage of it's new version still have the issue just comment to me to add my fix code